# Powershell script runs fine when I manually enter the commands, but fails when deployed with PDQ Deploy

Tags: powershell, deployment

I'm making a script to collect the names and paths of all mapped drives on the domain. Unfortunately, due to WMI permissions, I can't simply pull them over the network as I get a WMI access denied error when I run the script. So I thought instead I would deploy the script to run locally on each computer and have them write the results to a share location that all users have access to.

The script works fine when I manually type the commands into PowerShell, but when I try deploying it via PDQ Deploy the results file gets generated but is 0 KB. What could be causing it to fail when running via PDQ? I have also noticed that it only works locally when I run it as myself, if I run it as the local admin or domain admin it fails in the same way. Perhaps I need to have it run as a local user? Is there any way to do so?

```
$computername = hostname
Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -ComputerName $computername | Out-File -Append \\servername\results\results.txt
```

Comment: Mapped drives are per-user, not per-computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bill Stewart mentioned in the comments, mapped drives are per user. The values are stored in each user's registry. Here is a function that pulls the information from each user's `HKCU:\Network` and `HKCU:\Volatile Environment` (Drives mapped from AD Home Share) via PSRemoting.

```
function Get-MappedDrive {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $True, ConfirmImpact = 'Low')]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
            Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )

    begin {}

    process {
        if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerName)) {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {
                New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS | Out-Null
                Get-ChildItem HKU:\ |
                    ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem "$($_.pspath)\Network" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} |
                    ForEach-Object {
                        [PSCustomObject]@{
                            User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($_.name -replace 'HKEY_USERS\\(.*?)\\.*','$1')).Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
                            Drive = "$((Split-Path $_.name -Leaf).ToUpper()):"
                            Path = Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name RemotePath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RemotePath
                        }
                    }
                Get-ChildItem HKU:\ |
                    ForEach-Object {
                        if (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$($_.PSPath)\Volatile Environment" -name HOMEDRIVE -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                            [PSCustomObject]@{
                                User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($_.name -replace 'HKEY_USERS.(.*?)(\\.*|$)','$1')).Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
                                Drive = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$($_.PSPath)\Volatile Environment" -name HOMEDRIVE | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HOMEDRIVE
                                Path = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$($_.PSPath)\Volatile Environment" -name HOMESHARE | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HOMESHARE
                            }
                        }
                    }
                Remove-PSDrive HKU | Out-Null

            }
        }
    }
    end {}
}
```

As for why the PDQ Deploy Script is failing is that the PowerShell script is being run as an account without permission to the file share. You could use `net use \\server\folder username password` or `(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive('Z:','\\server\folder',$false, 'username', 'password')` to map the share with different credentials.